# What is the -i option while compiling hs file using GHC and how to do same in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Ok, I've been using the `-i` compile option to specify the folder to some haskell source when I compile using GHC.

```
ghc -threaded -i/d/haskell/src --make xxx.hs
```

I understand it uses those files as 'libraries' while compiling but can i do same in GHCi?

I usually import haskell prepackaged lib e.g. `import Data.List` or `:m +Data.List`.

I tried `import /d/haskell/src` -- does not work!

**EDIT**
From Haskell doc: [Chapter 2 Using GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html#ghci-modules-filenames)
Note that in GHCi, and `––make` mode, the `-i` option is used to specify the search path for source files, whereas in standard batch-compilation mode the `-i` option is used to specify the search path for interface files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '-i' flag is fine, the problem is with loading the module.

Within ghci, `:m` will only switch to either pre-compiled modules, or modules which were specified on the command-line.  You need to use `:add MyModule` to tell ghci to compile a Haskell source file.

If you have

```
./src/Module/SubModule.hs
```

you can load it with the following:

```
localuser$ ghci -isrc
GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :add Module.SubModule
[1 of 1] Compiling Module.SubModule        ( src/Module/SubModule.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Module.SubModule.
*Module.SubModule>
```

Comment: I managed to get around by doing: `ghci -i/d/haskell/src` (note there is no space after `-i`). Then i still needed to load my module using `:load` or i tested `:add` to work the same.

Comment: You can also specify it directly as an argument, `ghci -i/d/haskell/src /d/haskell/src/Module.hs` If you're only loading one module you don't even need the `-i`, but I usually have a lot of sub-modules to pull in which ghci won't find otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can say `:set -i /d/haskell/src`; many, but not all, GHC options can be set that way.  Alternatively, you should be able to use it as a parameter directly:  `ghci -i /d/haskell/src`.

Comment: note there is no space between `-i` and `/d/haskell/src`. If i try to compile with the space, i get this error: `targer ... is not a module name or a source file`. And i tried what you said, but i still can't use the functions defined in those files in the specified directory.